# Coldfusion 10 Websocket - How to get list of current subscribers?

Tags: javascript, coldfusion, websocket, coldfusion-10, cfwebsocket

Coldfusion has a set of javascript methods to use with the cfwebsocket tag but I'm trying to create a live chat admin area where once logged in, there will be a list of admins who are "logged in" (subscribed) to the chat, similar to OLark.
Once the admin page is loaded how can I get a list of "admin" users subscribed and list them on the page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to figure it out. There's a ColdFusion function named [wsGetSubscribers](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/10.0/CFMLRef/WSf23b27ebc7b554b66a72d1471360b6969d6-7fff.html) that will get a list of subscribers to a channel.

```
<cfset subscribers = wsGetSubscribers('chat')>
```

It returns an array of subscriber structs.